# Symfony JsonResponse with Serializer

Tags: php, json, symfony

I have a small problem. Maybe someone have an a idea.

I use Serializer in the following way. The problem that function json_encode is applied two times.

First when i call $serializer->serialize($post, 'json');

Second time in $response->setData();

So, to decode i need call function two times.

Any ideas?

```
$encoders = [
    new JsonEncoder()
];
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
$normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
    return $object->getId();
});
$normalizers = [$normalizer];
$serializer  = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData([
    'status' => true,
    'data'   => $serializer->serialize($post, 'json')
]);

return $response;
```

Comment: `'data'  => $post`?

Comment: Then i have problems with encoding my entity and circular reference.
Even if entity implements JsonSerializable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The object is encoded twice because you use a jsonresponse, use a simple response instead. In addition encode the entire data, not only part of them . As example:

```
$responseData = [
    'status' => true,
    'data'   => $post
];

$response = new Response(
   $serializer->serialize($$responseData, 'json'),
   Response::HTTP_OK,
   ['Content-type' => 'application/json']
);

return $response:
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks. Found solution to call getValues() at PersistantCollection. And implementing JsonSerializable in Entity. Without Serializer.

Comment: How can you add a parameter to the response ? Like `'success' => true`  ?

Answer (score 13):

To return a json `string` instead of an `array` use the `JsonResponse::fromJsonString` method:

```php
return JsonResponse::fromJsonString($serializer->serialize($data, 'json'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "pure" symfony answer, with the JsonResponse helper :

```
$doctors= $this->doctorsRepository->findBy_Name("dummy name"); // returns "Result" and NOT an "ArrayResult"

return new JsonResponse(
    $serializer->serialize($doctors, 'json', [
        ObjectNormalizer::GROUPS => ['for_importing_some_specific_fields']
    ]), // your serialized json but as a 'string' json
    200, // equivalent code for Response::HTTP_OK (success) 
    [], // headers (by default it is application/json because of the Jsonresponse class)
    true // already a json string so convert it to a json Object
);
```